# Proxy Redirect on NGINX not working as expected

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy, redirect

I set up nginx as a reverse proxy for two proxied servers. Each of them (proxy and proxied servers) is running as a container in a docker environment. Proxied server `appalpha` is simply an `nginx:alpine` serving a static webpage (just for demo and testing purposes). All works fine here because things are simple.
The other proxied server's image is `kanboard/kanboard`. When I try to access this service through my reverse proxy at `https://example.com/kanboard/` I first get an expected http response with status code `302 (Found)`. But the header is set to `Location: /login` (i.e pointing to my reverse proxy) which does not exist. My expectation is to see a header field of `Location: /kanboard/login` here.

I tried with several proposed configurations without success:

- without `proxy_redirect`
- with `proxy_redirect`
- with `rewrite` (which is not the right concept here, as far as I understand)
- with `return` (which is not the right concept here neither, right?!)

What am I doing wrong?

My `proxy.conf` of the nginx reverse proxy lists as follows:

```
server {
    listen                    443 ssl http2;
    server_name               example.com;
    server_tokens             off;
    ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key;
    ssl_session_cache         builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols             TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers               "HIGH !aNULL !eNULL !EXPORT !CAMELLIA !DES !MD5 !PSK !RC4";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    access_log                /var/log/nginx/nginx-2443.log;
    proxy_cache_valid         any 1s;

    location /alpha {
        proxy_set_header      Host $host;
        proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass            http://appalpha/;
    }

    location /eval_kanboard {
        proxy_set_header      Host $host;
        proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass            https://restore_eval_kanboard/;
    }
}
```

I appreciate your help.

Cheers Thomas

Comment: The redirect URL is generated by your application, so you need to look how to specify the base URL for `kanboard`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggested fix. I set the base URL in the application `kanboard` to `https://example.com/kanboard/`. Unfortunately getting the same `302 (Found)` response with `Location: /login`.
Isn't this one of the main features of a reverse proxy to be able to redirect/rewrite requests as well as responses?! And should the proxied server care in which environment it is running?! From the proxied server perspective, the _relative_ `Location: /login` _is_ correct, because it does not know about the reverse proxy. But the reverse proxy should be able to redirect/rewrite to `/kanboard/login`.

Comment: Such a rewrite cannot be implemented reliably in reverse proxy context. Reverse proxy only sees text stream, it doesn't have any idea of its organisation. The URLs can be in many formts in the text stream. Doing simple search & replace over the text stream can cause all kinds of bad side-effects. Therefore it has to be set up in the application.